# print to PDF using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

We are trying to use TSQL on SQL 2012 and OS 2012 to print PDF file from a specific directory using variables based on a lookup that populates these variables. The command we have works on SQL 2005 and 2003 datacenter OS. During our upgrade this now does not want to work. I am fairly sure we are just dealing with a syntax issue that is OS related but SQL is not saying what is the issue.

Here is the base query --

```
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe /t" \\jde9appb\d$\JDEdwards\E910\PrintQueue\R5509108_TV0001_4970_PDF.pdf \\VMPS08\INF2808P'
```

The above runs in the OS 2003 and SQL 2005 but when we try it in OS 2012 and SQL 2012 it just spins. We have turned of UAC and verified that the execute user has all the necessary rights to the command shell and command shell is enabled. This has to be done thru a TSQL script since this is part a stored proc that gets called by the custom application. Also the foixut reader is the default application to read PDF files. The switch you see above is the silient mode to print directly to a queue.

Help help. This has been a real tough one to figure out.

I have actually gotten it to say **Failure to initialize the printer** by messing with the Syntax, but this is as far as I have gone. I even loaded the printer I am going to to make sure the system is trying to use the proper driver.

For some reason the double backslash is not showing correctly. Here is the fixed query that I need some help with please.

```
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe /t" \\jde9appb\d$\JDEdwards\E910\PrintQueue\R5509108_TV0001_4970_PDF.pdf \\VMPS08\INF2808P'
```

Comment: For some reason the double backslash is not showing correctly. Here is the fixed query that I need some help with please.               EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe /t" \\jde9appb\d$\JDEdwards\E910\PrintQueue\R5509108_TV0001_4970_PDF.pdf \\VMPS08\INF2808P'

Answer (score 1):

We faced the exact same issue. We found it was caused by  the network printers, though created for the user, not being available to the background process. Creating the printers locally, thus bypassing the print server solved the issue.

Comment: I created local printer but still encounter the couldn't display Windows GDI Driver issue. The printer can be found by gsprint but just not sure why the driver issue keep nagging.